# Conditional path to deploy in cpanel.yml file configuration

Tags: linux, bash, deployment, path, repository

I need to deploy the same repository in different paths based on the current path of this file

****Example:****

If this **.Cpanel.yml** is in the repository located at **"/ home / foo / repository / foo_prod /"**, implement it at **/ home / foo / public_html / production_folder /** but if the file location binder **. cpanel.yml** is in **"/ home / foo / repository / foo_pre_prod /"** so implement it in **/ home / foo / public_html / pre_prod_folder /**

---

Current file .cpanel.yml

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/foo/public_html/xyz/
    - /bin/cp -R * $DEPLOYPATH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Solved my previous question! I share what I did. Thanks @Salines your
> anwer help me!

```
---
deployment:
tasks:
- current_path=`pwd` # set current path to variable
- if [ $current_path == "/home/user/repositories/p" ]; then export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/p/; fi;
- if [ $current_path == "/home/user/repositories/p_pre" ]; then export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/p_pre/; fi;
- /bin/cp -R * $DEPLOYPATH
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try something like this:

```
deployment:
  tasks:
    - current_branch=$(git branch --show-current) # set current branch to variable
    - if [ $current_branch == "master" ]; then export DEPLOYPATH=/home/foo/public_html/xyz/; fi;
    - if [ $current_branch == "develop" ]; then export DEPLOYPATH=/home/foo/public_html/xyz_dev/; fi;
    - /bin/cp -R * $DEPLOYPATH
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Lead me to the solution, however  `$(git branch --show-current)` was returning a `error: unknown option 'show-current'`... so I ended up using `$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)` which worked perfect.

Comment: I tried both methods, but I'm getting `error: unknown option `show-current'` 
ps: For others wondering: you could access your logs in /home/username/.cpanel/logs/vc_*_git_deploy.log - open the newest log.

Comment: @SvetoslavStefanov look here https://github.com/projectcontour/contour/issues/2414 and here https://www.techiedelight.com/determine-current-branch-name-git/

Comment: Thank you @Salines I'll look at these.
The support guy from my hosting provider pointed me to use /home/username/repositoryFolder/.git/hooks/post-receive git hook (for cPanel) for this purpose and I'll give it a try first.

Comment: The only way to get branch's name in post-receive hook was `branch=$(echo $ref | awk -F / '{ print $(NF) }')`